# Select grouped data for statistcs

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by, statistics

I have the problem, that I can't SELECT the data properly for a statistic tool.
The data has the groupable fields datetime and user id (fieldname: SID).

I get the data every 10 minutes via cron command (PHP / Linux). So the datetime field has everytime a very little difference like

```
2016-09-06 18:10:00
2016-09-06 18:10:05
```

Now I would like to SELECT "global" data summed from every user.
I tried this command, but

1. it is just one result per day (could be okay)
2. it adds the data from one user several times.

Command:

```
SELECT datetime, SUM(view) as viewer, SUM(follow) as follower, 
       SUM(inchat), game, title, online 
FROM `streamerdata` 
GROUP BY DATE(datetime)
```

So this command gives me very high results for the statistics, which are not true.

Is there a possibility to collect just one data row from each user per day / hour?

Comment: Why you get the update time from cron if you just need to sum stats per day ?

Comment: the statics, a single user can see, goes down to an overview of every 10 minutes.

Comment: Yes - it's possible - but you have to rewrite your query - you mention users - but I see no reference to user in your query - and if you want one line per user - group by the user itself...if you want more precise breaks in terms of time you can do that too

Comment: Well, if u want to get per hour , so u have to GROUP BY HOUR (datetime)

Comment: the bigger problem (for me) is that there is just one row of data per user per hour / date and I actually can't figure out that code

Answer (score 0):

You would include the user in the `group by`:

```
SELECT DATE(datetime), SID,
       SUM(view) as viewer, SUM(follow) as follower, 
       SUM(inchat), 
FROM streamerdata 
GROUP BY DATE(datetime), SID;
```

If by `"global" data summed from every user` you mean over all days, then just leave the date out of the `group by`:

```
SELECT SID,
       SUM(view) as viewer, SUM(follow) as follower, 
       SUM(inchat), 
FROM streamerdata 
GROUP BY SID;
```

Comment: @ChristopherSmith . . . "not work" is extremely vague and doesn't really communicate anything.